# Selenium Select from dropdown element not found in heroku, but found locally

Tags: python, selenium, datetime, heroku, html-select

I have created a python script to input in temperature by itself into a website, and it works locally. When I deployed it into Heroku, it worked as well. I also scheduled my app to run once in the morning and once in the afternoon, as per required.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')


browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"), chrome_options=chrome_options)
 
browser.get('https://temptaking.ado.sg/group/e306686f4e962fec4c8b20ea8e60d1fe')



select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('member-select'))

select.select_by_value('79563')

browser.find_element_by_id("ep1").send_keys("2084")

browser.find_element_by_id("td1").send_keys("36")


browser.find_element_by_id("td3").send_keys("5")

browser.find_element_by_class_name("btn")
submit = browser.find_element_by_class_name("btn-warning")

submit.click()

time.sleep(5)

subbmit = browser.find_element_by_id("submit-temp-btn")

subbmit.click()

browser.close()
```

However, there was an issue. The website has an AM and PM dropdown, which automatically changes (PM after 12pm). However, when I ran the script in the afternoon, the AM dropdown was still chosen.

I then tried to input in a couple more lines to choose the PM option from a dropdown if its not 8am, which is when I scheduled my app to run for the morning, using the following lines.

```
hour = dt.datetime.now().hour

if hour == 7:

    select2 = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('meridies-input'))
    time.sleep(3)
    select2.select_by_value('AM')
    select2.select_
else:
    select2 = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('meridies-input'))
    time.sleep(3)
    select2.select_by_value('PM')
```

However, once I pushed this into heroku and tried to run the script, I'm met with the NoSuchElementException error, where it can't locate the value "PM". I have tried to use index, select_by_visible_Text, even xpath as well, all gave similar errors, not being able to locate ___. I have included the time.sleep as I thought it was having issues loading but to no avail. What baffles me is that I have used a select from a dropdown in another part of the code but that has no issues, just this specific block.

I've been set back by this small problem, and it's bugging me so much. Please help.

Comment: Do you execute the script at **8 AM**and **8 PM** alternatively?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of headless use virtual display. (might your element depends on javascript)

use start() display before initialing chrome after all operation stop() display.

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
import os
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

display = Display(visible=False, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"), chrome_options=chrome_options)

# your code
#########

# at end stop display
display.stop()
```

Comment: I have attempted ur code, and included it although I'm not sure how it would fix the element not being found. In doing so, I encountered another error - 

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyvirtualdisplay'

I have also done pip install pyvirtualdisplay. not sure why that doesn't work. have attempted to google about it as well but i think it is specific to heroku.

Comment: are you using python3?

Comment: and if this method work on your local (can use visible=True) to see chrome than will run perfectly on server (keep in mind that in server it always run with visible=False)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of depending on the *AM* / *PM* default setting of the application server you should handle the selection of *AM* / *PM* on you own using the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://temptaking.ado.sg/group/e306686f4e962fec4c8b20ea8e60d1fe')
Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='meridies-input']")))).select_by_visible_text((datetime.now()).strftime("%p"))
```